# Loading text in tinyMCE for Wordpress via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE for Wordpress.
Which is the way to load text from server via AJAX?
Until now I have:

php:

```
<?php echo the_editor($_POST ? $_POST['content'] : '', $id = 'content'); ?>
```

javascript (which is failing...):

```
$("select[name='tpl']").live("change", function(e) {
    var file = $(this).val();
    var loadUrl = varsJs.WORDPRESS_PLUGIN_URL + "/templates/" + file;
    $.get(loadUrl, function(result) {
        $("#content").val(result);
    });
});
```

The variable `result` is loaded with the desired text. No problem with that. But how pass this content to the tinyMCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (typeof tinymce === "object"){
    $("select[name='tpl']").live("change", function(e) {
        var file = $(this).val();
        var loadUrl = varsJs.WORDPRESS_PLUGIN_URL + "/templates/" + file;
        $.get(loadUrl, function(result) {
            tinymce.get("content").focus();
            tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Note: `varsJs` is the second parameter of `wp_localize_script` function used to pass data from `php` to `javascript`. Really no needed in this precise issue but useful to know it.

Comment: For a general approach only 2 lines did the trick for me. Your data object returned from your ajax call will have the text you want in your editor. Use these lines                 tinymce.get("#idOfYourTextArea").focus(); and tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(data.content); where data.content is your dat you want to be stored in the tinyceMCE editor

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, where '**content**' is your field #ID

> tinymce.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit['content']);

this way and once tinymce is also loaded in current html,
you will reinit only one field, the one you received from Ajax Request.

also set this code before ajax saving Call

> tinymce.activeEditor.save(); // get editor instance